# iOS draw gradient in part of the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, graphics

I've created a custom progress bar which subclass UIView and implements drawRect. I manage to draw a single gradient on the entire view. I'd like however to draw several different gradients, each one in a different position. How to I limit `CGContextDrawLinearGradient` to smaller rect inside my view?

```
glossGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(rgbColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
CGPoint topCenter = CGPointMake(start + (CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds)/currentBounds.size.width), 0.0f);`
        CGPoint midCenter = CGPointMake(start + (CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds)/currentBounds.size.width), currentBounds.size.height);
        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);
        start = start + (values[i] / currentBounds.size.width);
        CGGradientRelease(glossGradient);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CGContectClipToRect` to restrict the drawing area

Then for each gradient do:

```
CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);
CGContextClipToRect(theRect); // theRect should be the area where you want to draw the gradient
... // gradient drawing code
CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [*Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-BBCBCJAE):

> When you paint a gradient, Quartz fills the current context. Painting
>   a gradient is different from working with colors and patterns, which
>   are used to stroke and fill path objects. As a result, if you want
>   your gradient to appear in a particular shape, you need to clip the
>   context accordingly.

Since you want to draw each gradient in a rectangle, you will want to do something like this for each gradient and rectangle:

```
CGContextSaveGState(currentContext); {
    CGContextClipToRect(currentContext, currentBounds);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext, glossGradient, topCenter, midCenter, 0);
} CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
```